# jQuery: Get index of hidden element relative to its neighbors

Tags: jquery, indexing

Lets say I want to get the index of each li within the unordered list bellow.

```
<ul>
   <li>index 0</li>
   <li class="hidden">index 1</li>
   <li>index 2</li>
   <li class="hidden">index 3</li>
</ul>
```

But lets say I want to dynamically get the index of all li with ".hidden" class, How would I get the index and still be relatable to all li.

If I do the following, it gets the index of all li with the class, but the li number 2 will have the index 0 instead of 1. and the last li with ".hidden" class will have index 1 instead of 3.

```
$("ul li").each(function(index) {
   $(this).index() // gets index of the alis (good)
   $("ul li.hidden").index() // gets index, but not related to all li
});
```

So how can i get the index of the .hidden li and have them be relatable to all other index

Comment: Did I make this clear enough?

Comment: Thought there would be a simple solution i havent figured out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use indexes from the $.each() function:

```
$("ul li").each(function(i, el) {
   if( $(el).is('.hidden') ) alert(i);
});
```